# SQL server alias

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created SQL server alias for a SQl 2005 named instance using SQL server configurations manager.
But I cannot connect to it using the alias name.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the SQL Browser service is running on your server.  This service resolves SQL aliases to the hostname/port combinations needed to make a connection.